# Angular Custom Validator causes form to be invalid

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am really trying hard to figure this out and read a lot of similar issues here on stackoverflow but nothing helped.

I am running on Angular 9 and I am trying to implement a custom validation which checks async if an email already exists. It seems to work at first glance, but when trying to submit the form, it says the form is invalid. But it is getting really weird when checking the FormGroup Object in which `valid` is `true`.

Thats my is im init:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.validateForm = this.fb.group({
      academicTitle: [null],
      birthday: [null],
      firstName: [null, Validators.required],
      company: [null],
      lastName: [null, Validators.required],
      gender: [null],
      email: [null, [Validators.email, Validators.required], [this.emailValidator(this.http)]],
      password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      password2: [null, [this.confirmPasswordValidator]],
      street: [null],
      zip: [null],
      city: [null],
      country: [null],
      role: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
```

Here my emailValidator

```
emailValidator(http: HttpClient): ValidatorFn  {
    return (control: AbstractControl) => {
      return http.get(serverConstants.serverUrl + 'user/checkEmail/' + control.value).pipe(map((res) => {
        if (res) {
          console.log('exists');
          return {
            error: true,
            duplicated: true
          };
        }
        console.log('NOT EXISTING');
        return null;
      }));
    };
  }
```

Here my Submit Method and as you can see I do check every contro lto be valid and then to form itself. It outputs always that it is not valid in the console, but the actual object contains valid = true.

```
submitForm() {
    for (const i in this.validateForm.controls) {
      this.validateForm.controls[i].markAsDirty();
      this.validateForm.controls[i].updateValueAndValidity();
      if (this.validateForm.controls[i].invalid) {
        console.log(i);
      }
    }
    console.log('is valid ? ' + this.validateForm.valid);
    console.log(this.validateForm);
    if (this.validateForm.valid) {
      this.saveUser();
    }
  }
```

That is the output in the console after filling all the neccessary field and pressing submit:

[image: Weird FormGroup behavior]

**UPDATE:**

I figured the status of the form is **"PENDING"** and it seems to be stuck on it. I did a lot of reading to this aswell but none of the fixes work for me or are outdated.

Comment: I could see FormGroup is valid in your screenshot.

Comment: @xDrago, can you paste your entire `SignupComponent` class?

Answer (score 0):

Where you are validating multiple conditions in a reactive form, you may need to use Validators.compose like so:

email: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required, this.emailValidator(this.http)])],

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the fix for my problem. What I dont understand why the `valiateForm.valid` is false when i do console.log. But when logging the Object itself right after that, it is true.

Comment: console.log(this.validateForm); <-- this is true because you're testing the object as a whole for truthiness. Meaning this would only log false if this.validateForm was null or undefined. Can't see what the existing form control values are from your screenshot. Could you add?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably implement [AsyncValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn) since HTTP request is asynchronous. At a glance your log seems to me that your form is invalid at the time, and become valid when you check your console. Chrome's console only evaluate the object value when you click into it. If you need the object value at the exact moment of console.log, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.validateForm))`